# Will polymorphism hold for C++ object references passed around in C?

Tags: c++, c, polymorphism

I have a C++ lib that makes use of a object hierarchy like this:

```
class A { ... }
class B : public A { ... }
class C : public A { ... }
```

I expose functionality through a C API via typedefs and functions, like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef A* APtr;
#else
    typedef struct A* APtr;
#endif

extern "C" void some_function(APtr obj);
```

However, say a use of the C API does something like this:

```
BPtr b = bptr_create();
some_function((APtr) b);
```

This is polymorphically valid, since B extends A, and my API depends on such functionality being possible, but I want to make sure that this will still interoperate properly with the C++ code, even if B overrides some of A's virtual methods.

More importantly, why or why not? How can C++ identify at runtime that the `obj` parameter of `some_function` is actually a pointer to B, and therefore call its overridden virtual methods instead?

Comment: You're using a C-style cast when calling `some_function`. This cast doesn't care whether `b` has the right type; if not, you'll simply get garbage results. Or worse, a hard-to-track and intermittent segfault or something like that.

Comment: @arne Is there a better solution? I was just assuming in this case that users of a library aren't stupid and don't try and pass something silly into `some_function`, but is that wrong?

Comment: Sadly, no. As long as your library (interface) has to be plain old C, you'll have to trust your users, or rather don't care if they choose to do something stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C code is not valid (nor would the equivalent C++ code in a context where the class definition is not visible) because what C does in this case is the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`. Note that in a simple situation like yours it will likely "work" because most compilers will put the single base object at the beginning of the derived object, so a pointer adjustment is not necessary. However, in the general case (especially when using multiple inheritance), the pointer will have to be adjusted to point to the correct subobject, and since C does not know how to do that, the cast is wrong.

So what is meant with "pointer adjustment"? Consider the following situation:

```
class A { virtual ~A(); int i; ... };
class B { virtual ~B(); int j; ... };
class C: public A, public B { ... };
```

Now the layout of `C` may be as follows:

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| A subobject (containing i) | B subobject (containing j) |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

where the virtual pointers of both the `A` and `B` subobjects point to `C`.

Now imagine you've got a `C*` which you want to convert to a `B*`. Of course the code which receives the `B*` may not know about the existence of `C`; indeed, it may have been compiled before `C` was even written. Therefore the `B*` must point to the `B` subobject of the `C` object. In other words, on conversion from `C*` to `B*`, the size of the `A` subobject has to be added to the address stored into the pointer. If you do not do this, the `B*` will actually point to the `A` subobject, which clearly is wrong.

Now without access to the class definition of `C`, there's of course no way to know that there even *is* an `A` subobject, not to mention how large it is. Therefore it is impossible to do a correct conversion from `C*` to `B*` if the class definition of `C` is not available.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're saying here. Could you explain why that's wrong?

Comment: Aha, thanks for the update. Do you know if the standard guarantees the behavior I'm looking for if I'm only using single inheritance? And either way, is there a better way to do what I'm looking for? Good answer, though, +1 from me.

Comment: I'm not aware of the standard guaranteeing anything about where base classes are placed in the derived class.

Comment: I can think of the following alternatives: 1. Have the C API just deal with A pointers, and if you need derived class features (try to minimize those cases), use a `dynamic_cast` in the wrapper layer and return an error to the calling C code if the object isn't of the right type. 2. Provide explicit conversion functions like `AfromB`. 3. If there are only a few derived classes which you need to expose, just write the interface wrapper functions for each one of them separately.

Comment: I wrote two blog entries a time ago on doing the equivalent of (multiple) inheritance in C. Maybe somebody will find it useful: http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2013/05/17/Exploring-C-Inheritance-1-of-2 and http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2013/05/17/Exploring-C-Inheritance-2-of-2

Comment: I just notice that I forgot the @JakeKing token in my latest comment, so I add it with this comment, in case you missed my previous comment because of it.

Comment: I saw it, thanks a lot. I think I'll probably go with option 1 to keep things simple, since I don't really need the complexities of the other options.

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses the virtual function table which is in memory per class ,
and when an object is created of that particular derived class its 
virtual table decides which function gets called.

So its bit c++ compile time  Plus Runtime magic :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes this will work.

Why: since `A` and `some_function` is implemented in C++, all virtual function calls will occur in C++ code as usual, where the class definition is included, and there is nothing magic about it. In C code only opaque pointers are passed around, and C code never will be able to call the virtual functions directly, because it never could compile the definition of `A`.